# Conversion from QList<QListWidgetItem *> to QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning to work with QT. While in such practice I've not managed to make a file dialog by seeing other examples where I show the files of a directory using a `listWidget`. Now, while I have this the list of files in a directory, I want to show another list of files in using a separate `listWidget` where I will only show the files that are selected by the user.

So for showing that I have the following code:

```
void MainWindow::showTheSelectedList()
{
    ui->selectedList->clear();
    ui->selectedList->addItems(originalFileList->selectedItems());
}
```

Here `originalFileList` is the first `listWidget` that shows the files originally in the directory and `selectedList` is the `listWidget` that shows the selected files. But here is where I run in to problem because `ui->selectedList->addItems()` can only take list of `QStringList` type while `originalFileList->selectedItems()` returns a list of `QList<QListWidgetItem *>` type. Could you please say how I can conver `QList<QListWidgetItem *>` to `QStringList`? A millions of thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QStringList stringList;
foreach( QListWidgetItem *item, originalFileList->selectedItems() )
    stringList << item->text();
ui->selectedList->addItems(stringList);
```

Comment: I actually though about this way. But, is there no direct conversion?

Comment: Even if there was a function called `toStringList()` that you could call on a `QList<QListWidgetItem*>`, it would just be doing the above conversion in the exact same way anyway.